# javax.imageio.ImageIO Problem creating ImageInputStream

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, inputstream, javax.imageio

I have a Servlet in Tomcat 5.5 that reads local images sitting on a folder.  The image is then sent back to an Applet.

I'm getting this "javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't create an ImageInputStream!" error and not sure whats causing it.

Has anyone had this problem before?  Could this be a Thread issue in the ImageIO?  I can't reproduce this issue since it occurs about 3 times for every 1000 requests.

EDIT: This is the Servlet code that reads the image.  I just use the ImageIO.read(File) in its static form inside the Servlet's doPost method the same way below:

```
    doPost(req,resp){
       ...
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
       ...
    }
```

Here is the source code for javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(File):

```
    public static BufferedImage read(File input) throws IOException {
    if (input == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("input == null!");
    }
    if (!input.canRead()) {
        throw new IIOException("Can't read input file!");
    }

    ImageInputStream stream = createImageInputStream(input);
    if (stream == null) {
        throw new IIOException("Can't create an ImageInputStream!");
    }
    BufferedImage bi = read(stream);
    if (bi == null) {
        stream.close();
    }
    return bi;
    }
```

Comment: Where's the code to createImageInputStream? Is it the static method in ImageInputStream, statically imported, or is it something else?

Comment: I call the ImageIO.read(File) from the Servlet doPost().

Comment: No, I mean you're making a call to `createImageInputStream` but it's not clear whether that's a statically imported call to ImageInputStream.createImageInputStream or something else.

Comment: @Jon that's most likely `ImageIO.createImageInputStream(...)`.

Comment: Oh createImageInputStream is a static method.  It is actually part of the ImageIO library.  The ImageIO is a Java library that I'm just using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source I have (Java5 but I doubt it has changed a lot) states that if there are no ImageInputStream service providers registered, the `createImageInputStream` method returns null and thus you get that exception.

From the JavaDoc on `IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance()` which is used by `ImageIO`:

> Each ThreadGroup will receive its own instance; this allows different Applets in the same browser (for example) to each have their own registry.

Thus it might actually be a threading problem in that you get a plain new instance of `IIORegistry`.

Edit: digging deeper into the source I found the following:

Most likely you'd get a `FileImageInputStream`, since you pass in a file. However, if an exception occurs the service provider returns `null`. Thus there might be a `FileNotFoundException` or any other `IOException` being thrown which causes the stream not to be created.

Unfortunately, there's no logging in the code, thus you'd have to debug somehow. It's probably due to missing file permissions, a corrupted/incomplete file or the file missing.

Here's the Java5 source for `FileImageInputStreamSpi#createInputStreamInstance()`

```
public ImageInputStream createInputStreamInstance(Object input,
                                                  boolean useCache,
                                                  File cacheDir) {
    if (input instanceof File) {
        try {
            return new FileImageInputStream((File)input);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess there should not be a Thread issue by doing ImageIO.read(File) inside the Servlet, correct?  Could it be a race condition on the Image.read(File) in cases when Servlet receives two or more simultaneous requests?  If not then I should probably start looking into your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If the sole functional requirement is to read images from local disk and return it *unmodified* to the HTTP response using a servlet, then you do **not** need the `ImageIO` at all. It only adds unnecessary overhead and other problems like you're having now.

Get rid of the `ImageIO` stuff and just stream the raw image straight from disk to HTTP response, along a set of proper response headers. For example,

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
File file = new File("/path/to/images", name);

response.setContentType(getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName()));
response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");

InputStream input = null;
OutputStream output = null;

try {
    input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

    for (int length; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
} finally {
    if (output != null) try { output.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
    if (input != null) try { input.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
}
```

That's all. You only need `ImageIO` whenever you would like to manipulate the image in server's memory before returning it, e.g. resizing, transforming or something.

Another, more robust, example of such a servlet can be found [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html) and a more advanced one [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html).

Comment: Yeah you're right.  I'll keep this in mind if I get the chance to modify my code.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your use of close() methods within the exception handling? Streams have to be closed when there are exceptions, too, as well as normal termination of the block of the code.

The symptom sounds like you run out of heap space or sometime.

It is not the coding errors that others pointed out, since the problem is intermittent.